# Upload pictures to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy my app on Heroku that allows users to upload pictures. For now I was saving these in local files, however Heroku is not allowing to amend the files.
What are my options?

I am using express.js server and express-fileupload to get the files.